# How come source can't see this conf file?

Tags: bash

I have 2 files in a directory; sh.sh and conf.conf. They look like this.

```
# conf.conf
HELLO=hello

# sh.sh
. conf.conf
echo $HELLO
```

In my terminal window, I can source conf.conf with the command

```
. conf.conf
```

and the command succeeds and I can `echo $HELLO` to the screen. However the identical command does not work when I run the script. I get the following error

```
sh.sh: 1: .: conf.conf: not found
```

If I change the script's interpreter to bash, then it works just fine. It also works if I change the command in the script to become `. ./conf.conf` . Why is this?

Comment: Hint: read the documentation for `.`. (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

Comment: I reopened this because the duplicate conflated two separate issues (`source` not being portable vs differences in search path) and was itself deduplicated to a page that didn't mention either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX specification for the `.` shell builtin is to search the file from paths in `$PATH`, similar to how executables are searched. It's a Bash extension that also searches the current directory for the file if it's not found in `$PATH`.

So `. ./conf.conf` is a POSIX-compliant way to do this, and you observe the behavior with both Bash and `sh`. However `. conf.conf` is Bash-specific (`sh` will only search `$PATH`) so you only get the result with Bash.